# Why is this code indented backwards in Glib?

Tags: indentation, gnu, glib

The below code is from Glib(glib/gmain.c:3629). As I know, Glib follows GNU style indentation. But I couldn't figure out why the '{' after the line 'if (!(source->flags & G_SOURCE_READY))' is indented backwards. Is there someone know why?

```
  while (g_source_iter_next (&iter, &source))                                   
    {                                                                           
      if (SOURCE_DESTROYED (source) || SOURCE_BLOCKED (source))                 
    continue;                                                                   
      if ((n_ready > 0) && (source->priority > max_priority))                   
    break;                                                                      

      if (!(source->flags & G_SOURCE_READY))                                    
    {                                                                           
          gboolean result;                                                      
          gboolean (* check) (GSource *source);                                 

          check = source->source_funcs->check;                                  

          if (check)                                                            
            {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely, tabs vs spaces.

Do not change the value of `\t` in your editor; `\t` should always map to 8 spaces.